# simplifying loop with loop carried dependency

Tags: racket

I am writing an interpreter for my own language. Is there a way to simplify the following interpreter loop?

```
(define (execute prog)
  (define e (create-new-env))
  (for ([s (statements prog)])
    (set! e (execute-stmt s e)))
  e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be nicer if you don't do a `for` with a `set!` inside, that's procedural programming and in Scheme we prefer the functional programming style. Please check if this works for you, I can't test it because you didn't provide all the required procedures:

```
(define (execute prog)
  (foldl execute-stmt
         (create-new-env)
         (statements prog)))
```

Notice how [`foldl`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29) allows us to express your use case in a functional way: we traverse the input list from left to right, processing each element and accumulating a result that was initialized at the beginning, updating the result at each step with a procedure that operates on the current element and the accumulated value. At the end, the accumulated result is returned.

Comment: I think you want `foldl` instead of `foldr`, so that you start executing the statements from the beginning (left) rather than the end (right). Also, Racket has `for/fold` that generalizes `foldl` to multiple accumulators and multiple sequences. It can be used in this example as follows: `(for/fold ([e (create-new-env)]) ([s (statements prog)]) (execute-stmt s e))`.